# where should I write html codes in php oop

Tags: php, oop

I have a (has a) relationship. an Article class has a Writer class.
one thing that I could not figure that out is the HTML code where should be written?

lets assume that we want to show the result in following blocks:

```
<div id="article_block">
  <h1>Article Title</h1>
  <p>Article content</p>
  <div id="writer_block"> writer name: <a href="writer_id"> Writer Name </a> </div>
</div>
```

should I create the #writer_block in Writer class and create #article_block in Article class, and mix them in Article class? what should I do, please help, I search a lot but nowhere mention that.
if there are issues with my perspective please do not tell me "don't reinvent the wheel". I don't try to do that, I just don't know the way, as I am new in OOP.

Comment: One option is to consider using a view, such as in [model view controller](https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/) patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the idea of Object Oriented programming is to break up your problem into self contained entities (objects) that you can then compose into your ultimate solution. Given that an `Article` has a `Writer`, it sounds like you need two classes, one for each.

Dealing first with the `Article` class, I imagine it should have a method to output your html lets call it `output()`. In this method you include the code for outputting the HTML thus calling `Article->output()` should return the HTML you need, but you could nest within this method a call to `Writer.output()` which should perform the same function but specific to the `Writer` class. in pseudocode `Article.output()` should:

1. output the first part of your HTML up to where you want the writer details.
2. call `Writer.output()`
3. output the closing tags and anything else you need.

The `Writer` class should essentially do the same thing you just specify different HTML for it to output.

You could make life easier on yourself by writing an `Entity` class as an abstract base that both `Article` and `Writer` inherit from then all you have to do is override the `output()` method in the derived classes to get the behaviour you desire.

[cale_b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870729/cale-b) is right though, taking your program and splitting it into a model/view/controller type architecture or a model/view/presenter architecture will make life easier for you in the long run if your system needs to grow.

- https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/
- http://phpenthusiast.com/object-oriented-php-tutorials/inheritance-in-object-oriented-php